# Which clustering algorithms can be used with Word Mover's Distance from M. Kusner's paper?

Tags: cluster-analysis, similarity, unsupervised-learning

I am new to machine learning and now I am interested in document clustering (short texts with different lengths) according to their semantic similarity (I just want to go beyond the standard TF/IDF approach). I read the paper http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf where the Word Mover's distance for word embeddings is explained. In the paper they used it for classification. My question is now - can I use it for clustering? If so, is there a paper where this kind of usage is discribed?

P.S.: I am basically interested in clustering which takes into account the semantic similarity, so even a word2vec or doc2vec approach will do the job - I just couldn't find any papers where they are used in a clustering problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could afford to compute an entire distance matrix, then you could do hierarchical clustering, for example.

It's easy today find other clusterings that accept any distance and use a threshold. These could even use the bounds for performance. But it's not obvious that they will work on such data.